# Parle-t-on d'un « corset lombaire » pour l'équipement de sécurité lors d'un déménagement etc. ?

Tags: vocabulaire, terminologie, synonymes

Dans une émission (*Hell's Kitchen*) j'entends quelqu'un dire à des gens qui doivent décharger un camion « pick up you back braces... » et je trouve le *corset lombaire* ([GDT](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/18084904/corset-lombaire), [Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=BACK%20BRACE&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs)) mais le contexte d'emploi semble être médical/thérapeutique et je me demandais si on avait un terme plus usuel pour ce genre d'équipement de sécurité servant à prévenir les blessures au dos lorsqu'on transporte des objets pesants (ex. déménagement etc.) ?

Answer (score 2):

J'entends plus parler de ***ceinture*** que de ***corset*** qui est plus orienté vers un contexte médical ou féminin.

Ce serait donc pour moi une ***ceinture de force***, ***ceinture lombaire*** ou ***ceinture de contention***.

Comment: Merci ! Quand le contexte est évident penses-tu réduire ça à _ceinture_ tout court, genre _bon là prends ta ceinture, on va lever le frigo_ ?

Comment: @solastalgienitsyne Oui, ça me paraît tout à fait possible. Plutôt d'ailleurs *mets ta ceinture* que *prends ta ceinture*.